# Dart gcloud package generating signed urls

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Dart's gcloud package documentation doesn't quite cover generating signed URLs for timed access to resources stored in cloud storage. Following this example, https://github.com/dart-lang/gcloud/issues/43#issue-223109847 I attempt to create a signed URL but I keep on getting this error `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.`
In the mentioned example what should the `stingToSign` contain?
I have a service account with object viewer permissions and I use the generated key.json file to get the access key.

I've tried `signer.sign(utf8.encode('https://storage.googleapis.com/$bucketName/$wordFile'))`, `signer.sign(utf8.encode('https://storage.googleapis.com/$bucketName'))`, `signer.sign(utf8.encode('$bucketName/$wordFile'))` and `signer.sign(utf8.encode('$bucketName/$wordFile'))` with no luck.

The bucket has uniform access control meaning no object-level ACLs are enabled.

**** EDIT ****

I followed the docs as @johnhanley posted and came up with the following code

```
Future<String> getWavSignedUrl(String wordFile) async {
    const expiration = 172800;
    final bucketName = dotenv.env['cloudWavBucket'];
    final canonicalUri = '/$bucketName/$wordFile';
    final dateTimeNow = DateTime.now().toUtc();
    final expirationDateStamp =
        '${dateTimeNow.year}${dateTimeNow.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}${dateTimeNow.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
    final expirationDateTimeStamp =
        '${dateTimeNow.toIso8601String().replaceAll('-', '').replaceAll(':', '').split('.')[0]}Z';
    final clientEmail = accountCredentials.email;
    final credentialScope =
        '$expirationDateStamp%2Fus%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request';
    final credential = '$clientEmail%2F$credentialScope';

    Map<String, String> headers = {};
    headers['host'] = '$bucketName.storage.googleapis.com';
    final sortedHeaderKeys = headers.keys.toList()..sort();
    var canonicalHeaders = '';
    var signedHeaders = '';
    for (var key in sortedHeaderKeys) {
      canonicalHeaders += '$key:${headers[key]?.toLowerCase()}\n';
      signedHeaders += '$key;';
    }
    signedHeaders = signedHeaders.substring(
        0, signedHeaders.length - 1); // remove trailing ';'

    Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters = {};
    queryParameters['X-Goog-Algorithm'] = 'GOOG4-RSA-SHA256';
    queryParameters['X-Goog-Credential'] = credential;
    queryParameters['X-Goog-Date'] = expirationDateTimeStamp;
    queryParameters['X-Goog-Expires'] = expiration;
    queryParameters['X-Goog-SignedHeaders'] = signedHeaders;

    var canonicalQueryString = '';
    final sortedQueryKeys = queryParameters.keys.toList()..sort();
    for (var key in sortedQueryKeys) {
      canonicalQueryString += '$key=${queryParameters[key].toString()}&';
    }
    canonicalQueryString = canonicalQueryString.substring(
        0, canonicalQueryString.length - 1); // remove trailing '&'

    String canonicalRequest = [
      'GET',
      canonicalUri,
      canonicalQueryString,
      canonicalHeaders,
      signedHeaders,
      'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD'
    ].join('\n');

    String canonicalRequestHash = base64.encode(utf8.encode(canonicalRequest));
    final stringToSign = [
      'GOOG4-RSA-SHA256',
      expirationDateTimeStamp,
      credentialScope,
      canonicalRequestHash,
    ].join('\n');

    final pem = accountCredentials.privateKey;
    final rsaKey = keyFromString(pem);
    final signer = RS256Signer(rsaKey);
    final signedRequestBytes = signer.sign(utf8.encode(stringToSign));
    final base64EncodedSignedRequest =
        Uri.encodeQueryComponent(base64.encode(signedRequestBytes));
    const schemeAndHost = 'https://storage.googleapis.com';
    final signedUrl =
        '$schemeAndHost$canonicalUri?$canonicalQueryString&x-goog-signature=$base64EncodedSignedRequest';
    return signedUrl;
  }
```

I am now getting the error

> `SignatureDoesNotMatch`
> Access denied.
>
> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.

Comment: Edit your post and include a minimum reproducible example showing the code you wrote and an example signed URL that is generated. I am not a Dart/Flutter developer but I have written URL signing code in multiple languages (C/C#/Go/PHP/Python). Tips: 1) make sure the time and time zone on your computer is correct 2) you must sign a lot more than the bucket/object name.

Comment: Refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually#algorithm) on the signing algorithm. One of the steps is to construct the URL to sign. None of the examples that you tried are correct.

Comment: thanks @JohnHanley for your response. For my code I had literally used the code in the link, word for word. I however followed the documentation link and came up with the following code and I get a signatur. posting the code shortly.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to signed urls is authenticated requests using access tokens. I achieved that using the following method.

```
import 'package:gcloud/storage.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart' as auth;
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class CloudStorageApi {
  late final auth.AccessCredentials _credentials;
  late final auth.ServiceAccountCredentials accountCredentials;
  final client = http.Client();

  CloudStorageApi(json) {
    accountCredentials = auth.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(json);
  }

  Future<void> getCredentials() async {
    final scopes = [...Storage.SCOPES];
    _credentials = await auth.obtainAccessCredentialsViaServiceAccount(
        accountCredentials, scopes, client);
  }
....

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getWavAuthenticatedUrl(String wordFile) async {
    await getCredentials();
    final bucketName = dotenv.env['cloudWavBucket'];
    String accessToken = _credentials.accessToken.data;
    Map<String, String> headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken'};
    return {
      'url': Uri.https('storage.googleapis.com',
          '/storage/v1/b/$bucketName/o/$wordFile', {'alt': 'media'}).toString(),
      'headers': headers
    };
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also needed this and I struggled for almost a day to figure it out, this is the working example based on the [python code](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually) from google:

```
import 'package:hex/hex.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/src/crypto/pem.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/src/crypto/rsa_sign.dart';

String generateSignedUrl(
    Map<String, String> serviceAccount,
    String bucketName,
    String objectName, {
    String? subresource,
    int expiration = 604800,
    String httpMethod = "GET",
    Map<String, String>? queryParameters,
    Map<String, String>? headers,
  }) {
    if (expiration > 604800) {
      print("Expiration Time can't be longer than 604800 seconds (7 days).");
      return '';
    }

    // Encoding the object name
    final escapedObjectName = Uri.encodeComponent(objectName);
    final canonicalUri = "/$escapedObjectName";

    final dateTimeNow = DateTime.now().toUtc();
    final requestTimestamp =
        DateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'").format(dateTimeNow);
    final datestamp = DateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(dateTimeNow);

    // Load your Google credentials and extract the client email
    final clientEmail =
        serviceAccount['client_email']; // Extract from service account file
    final credentialScope = "$datestamp/auto/storage/goog4_request";
    final credential = "$clientEmail/$credentialScope";

    headers ??= {};
    final host = "$bucketName.storage.googleapis.com";
    headers['host'] = host;

    SplayTreeMap splayTreeMap = SplayTreeMap.from(headers);//this orders the headers alphabetically, important!
    headers = Map.from(splayTreeMap);

    final canonicalHeaders = headers.entries
        .map((entry) =>
            "${entry.key.toLowerCase()}:${entry.value.trim().toLowerCase()}\n")
        .join();
    final signedHeaders = headers.keys.map((k) => k.toLowerCase()).join(";");

    queryParameters ??= {};
    queryParameters.addAll({
      "X-Goog-Algorithm": "GOOG4-RSA-SHA256",
      "X-Goog-Credential": credential,
      "X-Goog-Date": requestTimestamp,
      "X-Goog-Expires": expiration.toString(),
      "X-Goog-SignedHeaders": signedHeaders,
    });
    if (subresource != null) {
      queryParameters[subresource] = "";
    }

    final canonicalQueryString = queryParameters.entries
        .map((entry) =>
            "${Uri.encodeComponent(entry.key)}=${Uri.encodeComponent(entry.value)}")
        .join("&");

    final canonicalRequest = [
      httpMethod,
      canonicalUri,
      canonicalQueryString,
      canonicalHeaders,
      signedHeaders,
      "UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD",
    ].join("\n");

    final canonicalRequestHash =
        sha256.convert(utf8.encode(canonicalRequest)).toString();

    final stringToSign = [
      "GOOG4-RSA-SHA256",
      requestTimestamp,
      credentialScope,
      canonicalRequestHash,
    ].join("\n");


    var pem = serviceAccount['private_key'];
    var rsaKey = keyFromString(pem!);
    var signer = RS256Signer(rsaKey);

    List<int> stringToSignList = utf8.encode(stringToSign);
    var signedRequestBytes = signer.sign(stringToSignList);
    var signature = HEX.encode(signedRequestBytes);

    final schemeAndHost = "https://$host";
    final signedUrl =
        "$schemeAndHost$canonicalUri?$canonicalQueryString&x-goog-signature=$signature";
    return signedUrl;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code implementing Signed URLs in Dart.